# Share an applet across many jsp pages

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, applet

In my web application, a series of jsp pages are navigated.
These jsp pages appear on the Right Hand side (frame) of the screen.
On the left frame, I have an applet.

This applet is common to all jsps.
From all of the jsps, I want to invoke a method on the applet.
The javascript code is inside of each jsp.

Is there a way to do this ? Any approaches, suggestion, Code snippets most welcome.

The applet basically displays an image. Based on the user interaction in the jsp pages, the
image needs to change/rotate and so on. But the applet is common to all and should not be loaded on each of the jsps load. Thats why I am looking for a way for all jsps to communicate to the single applet (via javascripts of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that the Applet is in Frame F1, your javascript is in Frame F2 then you can call your Applet method from F2 with :

```
parent.f1.document.myapplet.mymethod("a");
```

Your Frameset :

```
<HTML><HEAD></HEAD>
<FRAMESET COLS="50%,*">
    <FRAME SRC="frame1.html" NAME="f1" >
    <FRAME SRC="frame2.html" NAME="f2">
</FRAMESET>
</HEAD>
```

The page with with the applet is

```
<HTML><HEAD></HEAD>
<BODY>
    <APPLET CODE="MyApplet.class" 
            NAME="myapplet" 
            HEIGHT=200 
            WIDTH=200>
    </APPLET>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible.See here for details [How to invoke invisible applet methods](http://rabout.com/?q=how_to_invoke_invisible_applet_methods%20)

Comment: But I dont want to embed the applet in each of the jsps. That is the catch. The applet needs to be invoked from a jsp where it is NOT embedded.